# Coupon code for free product with purchase over $99

Tags: custom, coupon, code

I want to create a **coupon code** to have a **specific product added to the cart** at no cost when the **order total** is over **$99** and the code has been entered.

I am not having any luck figuring out how to make this happen. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried the C4B_Free Product extension which is exactly what I need but there is an error. When I enter the desired sku and save the rule, the sku does not save. When i try the coupon code i created i get a 500 error.

Comment: contact `C4B_Free Product extension` once.....

Answer (score 0):

[Amasty's Special Promotions Pro](https://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html) has worked for me in the past.

(Using Magento 1.9.x) One way to try and achieve this without extra extensions would be to use a `Shopping Cart Price Rule` as such:

RULE INFORMATION:

- Rule Name should be the Value of "Free" Product (see below)
- Coupon is set to `No Coupon` - this will let it auto activate when
  conditions are met
- Priority is set to `0` - this will ensure it    overrides any other
  discounts with lower priority

CONDITIONS:

- Set to `All` are `True`
- `Subtotal` - is - `Equals or Greater Than` `99.00`

ACTIONS:

- Apply `Fixed Discount Amount`
- Discount Amount `XX.XX` (value of product eligible for free purchase)
- In `Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions` you should set: `All` are `True` & `SKU` - `is one of` - `ENTER SKUs that match value of discount`

You would need to create this for every different value associated to the products you have for sale. It's tedious and would need to be constantly updated when new product comes available.

Comment: Thanks Steven but $129 is pretty steep for what I need it for. I am hoping for a work around.

Comment: Agreed, their extensions are pricey and come with 3 months "free" support - but they do a lot and hardly ever conflict with other extensions. Which version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the C4B_FreeProduct extension a bit and saw that others had had the same issue I did and that in time it corrected itself. I ran a few random file uploads, cleared the cache and re-indexed a few times and now it works great. Thank you Steven foryour workaround. I will give it a try if this causes any problems.